# center a div (absolute position and width)

Tags: javascript, css, html, center

i use below css to center my div with absolute position:

```
#mydiv {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 121px;
    height: 121px;
    margin-top: -60.5px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -60.5px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
}
```

It works like magic.
But as you can notice, it has fixed width and height.

Now i have to use this same css but for my div which has no fixed width and height, as it uses responsive layouts.

I just want to know is there any simplest way to set my div width dynamically in css by javascript or so?  i.e., it count my div width on page load and than set to a negative number 1/2 of your it in margin-left?

Comment: can't u specify the width and height in % instead of px?

Comment: Using JavaScript to calculate the dimensions of the element and modify the margin-left/top accordingly is most likely going to require recalculating each time the browser is resized or the user rotates their handheld device.

Answer (score 7):

You can center a `fixed` or `absolute` positioned element setting `right` and `left` to `0`, and then `margin-left` & `margin-right` to `auto` as if you were centering a `static` positioned element.

```css
#example {
    position: absolute;
    /* center the element */
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /* give it dimensions */
    min-height: 10em;
    width: 90%;
}
```

### See this example working [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rwd4/).

Comment: what if I don't have a set width on my div; it fits the content size. this no longer works.

Comment: Yes, you need to set a `width` to get this working. [the `width` property initializes to `auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width), and absolute positioned elements with `width: auto` will adjust their width to fit the content size. If the content's width is unknown nor can be known, maybe you should reconsider the way you are styling the markup or ask another question in SO. The OP asked for how to center *an absolute positioned element, with a set width*.

Answer (score 1):

use to

```
display table-cell
```

**as like this**

**Css**

```
.parent{
    display:table-cell;
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px red;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:400px;

}
.child{

    display:inline-block;
    background:green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="parent">

    <div class="child">i m child div</div>

</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/X9kJS/2/)**

Comment: This seems too verbose and this extra markup is not needed. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem trying to center captions of varying lengths in a slideshow.

To center an absolute positioned element that has a dynamic width you can use transform: translateX. With prefixes this works in most modern browsers. Like so:

```
div {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign a class to all the divs that you want positioned like that, and then just select all of them and do the calculations.

```
$("body").find(".center").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "margin-left": "-" + ( $(this).width()/2 ) + "px",
        "margin-top": "-" + ( $(this).height()/2 ) + "px"
    });
});
```

Though, beware that this is a bad way of doing things, mainly because it's slow, your containers are not flexible and if you don't wait for the centering you may have flashes of unformatted content.